# Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class not found

Tags: php, wordpress, class

I am trying to add a new Skin (page layout) to the Wordpress Plugin Visual Product Configurator - Nom Lava Skin add on

I duplicated/renamed an existing skin, found all instances that it was used in the plugin folder and added the line of code. Steps I followed:

**1. In /Skins folder I have a new copied php file -

> class-vpc-In-browband-skin.php

**

I renamed the class:-

`VPC_In_browband_Skin {`

So it is now identical in code to the other two skins with a different filename and the class name changed.

**2. I added a line of code to require that php script is included to this file

> vpc-Ins.php

**

```
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-vpc-lns.php'; 

require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'skins/class-vpc-ln-left-sidebar-skin.php';  
require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__ ) . 'skins/class-vpc-ln-right-sidebar-skin.php';  
require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'skins/class-vpc-In-browband-skin.php';
```

All I did was added another line to the previous two skins, which are working ok.

**3. I added a line on this file:-

> class-vpc-ins-admin.php

**

```
public function vpc_custom_skin ($skins){
    $skins["VPC_ln_browband_Skin"] = "Browband Skin";
    $skins["VPC_ln_left_sidebar_Skin"] = "Lom-Nava Left Sidebar";
    $skins["VPC_ln_right_sidebar_Skin"] = "Lom-Nava Right Sidebar";

    return $skins;
}
```

I have created a site on dreamweaver in my localhost and search for every instance of the other two skins

> VPC_In_left_sidebar_Skin and VPC_In_right_sidebar_Skin

There are no other instances of it in the Add on Skin file or the main Configurator page, logically if I follow the exact same format, it should surely show up.

I can add the skin layout to my configuration, it shows up correctly as Browband Skin, but when I come to display the configurator, I get this

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'VPC_ln_browband_Skin' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pinknew\wp-content\plugins\visual-product-configurator\public\class-vpc-public.php:194

The line 194 the error refers to `$editor = new $skin($product_id, $config_id);`

If I change the skin to any of the other two skins, left/right sidebar, it works.

I tried adding the php script to the main configurator file/folder where the default skins are, and I get a message cannot redeclare.. surely that suggests that it is finding the class??

I appreciate this may be too much to ask of the stack overflow contributors, but am hoping that someone out there may be familiar with this product and be able to tell me what I am missing here..(software providers answer to support was "**We are sorry but we do not support when user makes changes in our plugin.** ) I am totally stumped.

Comment: It's hard to say but the problem is `VPC_In_browband_Skin` class couldn't be found in the **class-vpc-public.php** file, that could be caused by many problems, a typo, or maybe the Class file is not loaded.

Comment: problem is that when I put the class file in the main plugin it says cannot re declare class as if it already found it in the original location?   So I then took it out of the original leaving it in the main plugin folder only and we are back to it cant find it?

Comment: I can't tell for sure the problem's source as I need to go through the plugin, and that's a lot to be honest.

Comment: yes I expected that would be, thank you for your answer anyway, I shall have to hope someone who uses this plugin may be able to say "ahah" and help me, I am really stuck

Comment: actually you have given me the answer!! well done!  If you look carefully after the VPC_ there is a different, what I thought a letter I was actually a number 1 (one).

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this rather than delete it, because it seems such a simple error but if anyone else uses this plugin, what seems like a letter I is actually a number 1 (one) thumbs up @ Mehdi Bouyna for making me take a really close look at it!

You can see on my point 2. the part of code, its clearer on there, the file title and other instances of the error arent so clear.

I changed the " I " for a "1" and problem solved!